# Issue with plugin compatibility in SonarQube 4.5.6

Tags: sonarqube

After I deployed sonar 4.5.6, I installed some plugins:checkstyle 2.4,pmd 2.5 and find bugs 3.3. But,when I use the sonar (jdk 1.7) it reports errors:

```
Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.1:sonar (default-cli) on project bacs: 
Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.1:sonar failed: 
An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.1:sonar: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.sonar.plugins.java.api.JavaResourceLocator.classpath()Ljava/util/Collection;
```

Comment: it just occurs when i add findbugs or checkstyle or pmd rules.

Comment: Which version of the Java plugin do you have?

Comment: i've fixed it by update sonar to the latest version,thanks